# display only subcategories grid with images on homepage

Tags: magento-1.9, grid

I am trying to display my subcategories in a grid with respective images on my homepage. I got everything workin but the images. What am I missing? the link to the page is colagenosnella.com.br, Code follows. Thank in advance.

```
<?php
/*
* http://fishpig.co.uk - Magento Tutorials
*
* Display top level categories and subcategories
*
**/
?>
<?php $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category') ?>
<?php $_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories() ?>
<?php $currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category') ?>

<?php if (count($_categories) > 0): ?>

    <?php foreach($_categories as $_category): ?>


            <div style="float: left; padding-right: 18px; ">    

            <?php $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId()) ?>
            <?php $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories() ?>
            <?php if (count($_subcategories) > 0): ?>

                    <?php foreach($_subcategories as $_subcategory): ?>

                            <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subcategory) ?>">
                            <img src="<?php echo $_subcategory->getImageUrl() ?>" width="200" height="200" />
                                <?php echo $_subcategory->getName() ?>
                            </a>

                    <?php endforeach; ?>

            <?php endif; ?>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any source in your image tag when visiting your site. For example on the first sub-category you are displaying "Beleza Da Pele" the source shows;

```
<img src(unknown) width="200" height="200">
```

Looking at your code and testing it myself on a development site I see that the method `getImageUrl()` does not return anything. I believe this is to do with the method you are using to retrieve the collection of categories: 'getChildrenCategories()' from the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Category` class.

According to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28705008/get-category-image-in-with-getchildrencategories-getimageurl-magento); that method will only retrieve the sub-category's name, urlKey, children and is_anchor attributes.

In short I believe you need to use a different method to initially retrieve your categories or if you are not confident find a good tutorial. From the code you have supplied I see it is from FishPig, who are good but I suspect you may be reading an outdated post.

Best of luck.